# How to show error message for null or empty value of json in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I have some div coming from json with ng repeat.I need to set message for the column where my value is null or empty.For example my first value is empty,in that place I need to set message"value is empty".Here is the code below,can anyone please me.

### html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div class="main">
<div class="status" ng-repeat="emp in groups" ng-attr-id="{{emp.name}}">
{{emp.name}}
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

### script

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
$scope.groups = [
    {
      name: '',
      symptom:'fever',
      categoty:'critical',
      id:'1'
    },

    {
      name: 'cancer',
      symptom:'diesease',
      categoty:'critical',
      id:'3'
    },
    {
      name: 'fever',
      symptom:'diesease',
      categoty:'critical',
      id:'3'
    },
    {
     name: 'Cold',
      symptom:'colds',
      categoty:'major',
      id:'2'
    },

    ]

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `ng-if` statement and try with this:

```
 <div class="status" ng-repeat="emp in groups" ng-attr-id="{{emp.name}}">
    <div ng-if="emp.name !== ''">{{emp.name}}</div>
    <div ng-if="emp.name === ''">value is empty</div>
 </div>
```

plunker: http://next.plnkr.co/edit/J3d9i4KIcUUiKVLs?preview

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
<div class="status" ng-repeat="emp in groups" ng-attr-id="{{emp.name}}">
   {{emp.name.length > 0 ? emp.name : 'Value is empty'}}
</div>
```